# AWS SSL Certificates with old Android phones

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssl

I recently updated the SSL certificates of my app to use AWS certificates behind a load balancer, however, ever since then, my old android phone, running ICS is now getting this error: `ssl=0x56ded8d0 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=104 sslError=5 timeout_millis=2500`. Not really sure what's causing this issue. The app works just fine on new android phones. All devices were tested with the same wifi network, so it's not a network issue for sure.

Comment: If the device has not been updated recently, might it be possible that the ACM CA is not trusted by the device?

Comment: just trying to guess... android ICS does not support TLSv1.1 nor TLSv1.2, and supports only old cipher suites as well https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

Comment: @nandsito That was the issue! Thanks! Can you put this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android ICS does not support TLSv1.1 nor TLSv1.2, and supports only old cipher suites as well. https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html